# Term for system that is "Create, Read" enabled, but "update, delete" disabled?

Tags: read-only

Researching legal and regulatory compliance for creating systems are tamper resistant, and wondering if there is a term for a system that is "Create, Read" enabled, but "update, delete" disabled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The term that comes to mind is [WORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once_read_many) (Write once, read many). This is typically applied to types of backup media where bits cannot be modified once written.